# RuntimeError while opening deploy.prototxt

Tags: python, caffe

I'm trying run a simple code with caffe that should open `deploy.prototxt` but it couldn't open the file and throws this error

```
RuntimeError: Could not open file /home/ebadawy/git/caffemodels/bvlc_reference_caffenet/deploy.prototxt
```

this is my code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10, 10)        # large images
plt.rcParams['image.interpolation'] = 'nearest'  # don't interpolate:     show square pixels
plt.rcParams['image.cmap'] = 'gray'  # use grayscale output rather than a (potentially misleading)
                                     # color heatmap
caffe_root = '/home/ebadawy/git/caffe'

import os
if os.path.isfile(caffe_root + 'models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/bvlc_reference_caffenet.caffemodel'):
    print('CaffeNet found.')
else:
    print('Downloading pre-trained CaffeNet model...')
    os.system('../scripts/download_model_binary.py ../models/bvlc_reference_caffenet')

import caffe

caffe.set_mode_cpu()
model_def = caffe_root + 'models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/deploy.prototxt'
model_weights = caffe_root + 'models/bvlc_reference_caffenet/bvlc_reference_caffenet.caffemodel'

net = caffe.Net(model_def,      # defines the structure of the model
            model_weights,  # contains the trained weights
            caffe.TEST)     # use test mode (e.g., don't perform dropout)
```

I'm using archlinux+python3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I forgot to append `/` for `caffe_root` "very silly mistake!"

Answer (score 0):

add backslash at the end of your caffe_root like

```
caffe_root = '/home/ebadawy/git/caffe/'
```

I guess your path should refer to caffe/models , not caffemodels.
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using the absolute path to the directory that contained the `deploy.prototxt` file.