# RuntimeError: Could not open file caffenet/deploy.prototxt

Tags: python-2.7, caffe, google-colaboratory

I am getting this error in google colab

RuntimeError: Could not open file caffenet/deploy.prototxt

this is the code cell it is running on

```
net = caffe.Net("caffenet/deploy.prototxt",
                 "caffenet/bvlc_reference_caffenet.caffemodel",
            caffe.TEST)
```

have already searched for a solution here

[RuntimeError while opening deploy.prototxt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36828380/runtimeerror-while-opening-deploy-prototxt)

and here

[RuntimeError while opening deploy.prototxt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36828380/runtimeerror-while-opening-deploy-prototxt/36846995#36846995)

but they do not solve the issue, might be related to google colab itself

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. I figured out I was using the wrong caffemodel.
I listed down all the files using !ls and it showed different caffemodels.
I was earlier mentioning 735 but it had no such file. Except the ones with 270.
Changes the name and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

change the name of your file to prototxt.txt and it should work